# How do I pass font names to webfont.load as a string

Tags: javascript, google-webfonts

I am using basic font loading like this:

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: [ 'Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne' ]
    }
});
```

But I need to pass the font names to this as a string. Something like:

```
var fntstr = "'Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne'";
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: [ fntstr ]
    }
});
```

Why doesn't this work? Isn't that just a json structure being passed to Webfont.load?

Comment: Why a string? The parameter is an array so why not just create an array of font family names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, families is an array containing 3 strings.

```
['Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne']
```

In your second example, families is an array containing 1 string.

```
["'Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne'"]
```

To make this work, you want to do something like the following:

```
var fntstr = "'Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne'";
var fntarr = fntstr.split(',');
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: fntarr
    }
});
```

The split method will split your string at each comma and create an array with the elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools as it contains a lot of erroneous information and the examples are of extremely poor quality.

Comment: Can't I just create an array then instead of splitting?

var fntstr = ['Droid Sans','Cookie','Parisienne'];

Comment: @DougWolfgram You can just create an array like that. I added the split method so you could use the string in your example.